# Vuforia and Unity multi scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, scene

I have to make an augmented reality book app using Vuforia and Unity. My Android apps size is 108mb. It's not working with 1GB RAM devices. I want to split the scene into different scenes and load the corresponding scene when a specific image target is found.

Main problem is, that one scene load is huge*. So I need to split the scene and load each scene when an image target is found.

*Editors Note: I don't know wether he means huge perfomance-wise or storage size. Latter means, that he apparently wants to load the scene in runtime from another location.

Comment: well, then do it, make several scenes. Whats your specific problem?

Comment: I have make several scene but only work 1st scene when make app. Other scene dont load. I want other scene load when image target found.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the names of each of the image target prefabs  -

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Collections;
 
public class loadNewScene : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler {
     
    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
     
     
    void Start () {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
        }
    }
     
    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                    TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                    TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED)
        {
            switch( mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName ){
                case "Railway" :
                Application.LoadLevel( "rail" );
                break;

                case "Tree" :
                Application.LoadLevel( "tree" );
                break;
            }
        }
    }
     
}
```

Comment: Hi @Arriving from the sky , thanks for your answer, I want to use total 5 scene called scene1, scene2, scene3, scene4, scene5. So how will code for this line- SceneManager.LoadScene("NAME_OF_YOUR_SCENE");

Comment: You want to load a new scene everytime an image target is found ?

Comment: Yes. I want new scene every time.

Comment: I edited my code. Check it out. You can do that using switch case

Comment: I have used your code on every target image using game object. but its not working. Can you please help something more?